# Transform a code in to a function

Tags: function, arrays

How to transform this code :

```
    <?php
                    if(have_posts()):

                    $end = array(3,6,9,12,15,18,21,24,27,30,33,36,39,42,45);
                    $a = 0;
                    while (have_posts()) : the_post();
                    $a++;
                    global $post;
                ?>
                <li class="item_list<?php if (in_array($a, $end)) { echo " right"; } ?>">
```

in to a function that would start like this

```
$display =
```

Thank YOu so much in advance :)

Comment: This is a **PHP** question, *not* a **WordPress** question.

Comment: it is within wordpress. I'm trying to call a function to display the code that displays posts. Can You help me?

Comment: Remove the context of WordPress, and your question remains *entirely the same*. That the question is asked within the *context* of WordPress is irrelevant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can't turn your code into a function because it is part of an if/while/endwhile/endif structure;

to achieve what you want, try alternatively to use the modulus operator:

```
<?php           
  if(have_posts()):             
     $a = 0;               
     while (have_posts()) : the_post(); 
        $a++;          
        global $post; ?> 

        <li class="item_list<?php if ($a%3 == 0) { echo " right"; } ?>">
```

Comment: `<?php if(++$a%3==0) echo 'right'; ?>` Then you can remove the `$a++;` (I'm a sucker for the shortest method, anybody shorter?) +1 though.

Answer (score 0):

To use WordPress Objects the correct way I would point to use "$wp_query->current_post", instead of doing this sort of counting.

Example below:

```
if( have_posts() ) {
    // Before the loop

    while( have_posts() ){
        the_post();
        // The loop
        echo "<li class='" . ( $wp_query->current_post % 3 == 0 ? "right" : "" ) . "'></li>";

    }
    // After the loop

} else {
    // If don't have any posts
}
```